# trying to give "right/path/to/endpoint" but 404 not found returns

Tags: php, apache

I put a backend files into `/www` folder, but can't return the endpoint it's giving `404`. When I try to access the `domain.com/api/schedule` it returns `You don't have permission to access /api/schedule/ on this server.` but if I try to reach endpoint which is `domain.com/api/schedule/read` then it's giving the `404 not found`

inside the `read.php` I include files from different folders. like below.

```
include_once "../../config/Database.php";
include_once "../../models/User.php";
include_once "../../models/Schedule.php";
include_once "../../models/Blank.php";
```

So i am not very sure, 404 not found error about the path "../.." or not

and here is the /www/ access of in apache `.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:8005>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rest_backend
    <Directory /var/www>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

what do I missing here?

Comment: Try `domain.com:8005/api/schedule/read.php`

Comment: yes, you are right! it was very simple touch that i really didn't think about. because on the local didn't need it `.php` ... thank you.